# Get places that aren't reserved in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the table for my places(eventos_espacios), where I have the columns:

```
idPlace, name, minCapacity, maxCapacity, and cleaningTime
```

And I have the reservations table (eventos_evento_reservacion), where I have:

```
idReservation, idPlace, startDate, endDate, and wantedCapacity
```

Here's my sample data:

```
DECLARE @eventos_espacios TABLE (idPlace INT, name varchar(20), minCapacity INT, maxCapacity INT, cleaningTime INT)
INSERT INTO @eventos_espacios
SELECT 1, 'Conference Room', 20, 50, 120

SELECT *
    FROM @eventos_espacios

DECLARE @reservations  TABLE (idReservation INT, idPlace INT, startDate datetime, endDate datetime, wantedCapacity INT)
INSERT INTO @reservations
select 1, 1, '2018-08-07 18:00','2018-08-07 21:00',45

SELECT *
    FROM
    @reservations
```

F/E: 
I have an event that goes from today from 15 to 17:30 hrs. in the place with id = 1, which has a cleaning time of 120 minutes. 
I'd really like to get all the available places from @eventos_espacios that aren't reseved in @reservations and I can use from 15 to 19:30 hrs considering also that the place that are already reserved do not include the cleaningTime.
I have something like this, but it seems that some cases are not considered and I can't figure out why.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ee.idPlace,
ee.name
FROM @reservations eer
INNER JOIN @eventos_espacios ee on ee.idPlace = eer.idPlace
WHERE 30 between ee.minCapacity and ee.maxCapacity
AND ee.idPlace NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    ee.idPlace
    FROM @reservations eer
    INNER JOIN @eventos_espacios ee on ee.idPlace = eer.idPlace    
    WHERE ( 
                ( '2018-08-07 15:00' >= startDate AND '2018-08-07 17:30' <= DATEADD(MINUTE,ee.cleaningTime,endDate)) or 
                ( '2018-08-07 17:30' > startDate AND '2018-08-07 17:30' < DATEADD(MINUTE,ee.cleaningTime,endDate)) or 
                ( '2018-08-07 15:00' > startDate AND '2018-08-07 15:00' < DATEADD(MINUTE,ee.cleaningTime,endDate)) or 
                ( '2018-08-07 15:00' < startDate AND '2018-08-07 17:30' > DATEADD(MINUTE,ee.cleaningTime,endDate)) or 
                ( startDate >= '2018-08-07 15:00' AND DATEADD(MINUTE,ee.cleaningTime,endDate) <= '2018-08-07 17:30') 
          )
)
```

This shouldn't return the next information:

```
1   Conference Room 20  50  120
```

Because with the 120 minutes of the cleaningTime added to '2018-08-07 17:30' the place would be free until '2018-08-07 19:30' and there's already a reservation from '2018-08-07 18:00' to '2018-08-07 21:00'.

The same should happen with an event from '2018-08-07 21:00' to '2018-08-07 22:00', because the reservation with idPlace = 1 should consider the cleaningTime and it should be free until 23 hrs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: You want to get a list of places for a specific time slot (between start datetime to end datetime), that do not have a row in the reservations table in that time slot. The cleaning time for each place gets added to the end datetime, so if you have a time slot that ends at 17:00 and a cleaning time of 30 minutes, the actual end time is 17:30, right? What I'm not sure about is when you insert a record to the reservations table, does the end time for that record includes the cleaning time, or not?

Comment: @ZoharPeled When I insert a record in the reservations table, it does not include de cleaning time. I should take it from the eventos_espacios with the idPlace from reservations.

Answer (score 0):

Took a stab at this:

```
declare @start datetime = '2018-08-07 15:00'
declare @end datetime = '2018-08-07 17:30'
declare @capacity_needed int = 30

DECLARE @eventos_espacios TABLE (idPlace INT, name varchar(20), minCapacity INT, maxCapacity INT, cleaningTime INT)
INSERT INTO @eventos_espacios
SELECT 1, 'Conference Room 1', 20, 50, 120
union
SELECT 2, 'Conference Room 2', 20, 50, 15
union 
SELECT 3, 'Conference Room 3', 20, 50, 30
union 
SELECT 4, 'Conference Room 4', 20, 150, 180
union 
SELECT 5, 'Conference Room 5', 5, 20, 10

SELECT *
FROM @eventos_espacios

DECLARE @reservations  TABLE (idReservation INT, idPlace INT, startDate datetime, endDate datetime, wantedCapacity INT)
INSERT INTO @reservations
select 1, 1, '2018-08-07 18:00','2018-08-07 21:00',45
union all
select 1, 2, '2018-08-07 18:00','2018-08-07 21:00',30
union all
select 1, 3, '2018-08-07 18:00','2018-08-07 21:00',30
union all
select 1, 5, '2018-08-07 18:00','2018-08-07 21:00',15

SELECT *
FROM
@reservations

select e.*
from @eventos_espacios e left join @reservations r on r.idPlace = e.idPlace
where (r.startDate >= DATEADD(minute, e.cleaningtime,  @end)
or r.idReservation is null) and @capacity_needed between e.minCapacity and e.maxCapacity
```